# Formatar uma string com hora

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, string, datetime

Estou tentando formatar uma *string* que já possui data e a hora, mas esta *string* só tem que receber a hora estou tentando desta forma mais não funciona:

Recuperando da base de dados.

```
string dtSolicitacao = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(drv.Row["dtSolicitacao"])) ? "--" : Convert.ToString(drv.Row["dtSolicitacao"]);
```

E aqui tentando formatar só com a hora:

```
string IdentNomeHorario = "";
        IdentNomeHorario += "</br>Nome: " + Apelido;
        if (dtSolicitacao != "--")
            IdentNomeHorario += " " + String.Format("{0:HH:MM:ss}", dtSolicitacao);
```

Comment: O que não funciona? Como a hora está vindo da base?

Comment: A hora da base esta vindo assim 27/08/215 09:06:33, eu queria formatar só para mostrar o hora 09:06:33 sem o dia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
String.Format("{0:HH:MM:ss}", DateTime.Parse(dtSolicitacao))
```

Ou então, de uma forma mais porca pode dar um [`.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a(v=VS.110).aspx) na data:

```
IdentNomeHorario += " " + dtSolicitacao.Split(' ')[1];
```

Mas recomendo a primeira opção, claro.

Comment: Obrigado DontVoteMeDown pela ajuda.

Comment: @krispim precisando estamos ae.

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer isto que é mais elegante:

```
DateTime.Parse(dtSolicitacao).TimeOfDay
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Y2xBD0). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mPjmmO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/ParseStyles.cs).

De qualquer forma, tenha certeza que o formato da data está correto. Se não estiver é melhor tratar isto antes de dar uma exceção. Por isso a solução correta é não gravar uma data como *string* no banco de dados. Isto é uma prática ruim em vários sentidos.

Tem uma forma que pode lhe agradar mais se a data pode estar errada:

```
DateTime horario2;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dtSolicitacao), DateTimeStyles.None, out horario2)) {
    Console.WriteLine(horario2.TimeOfDay);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("deu erro"); //trate como achar melhor aqui, este foi só um exemplo
}
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__).

Comment: Boa colocação sobre o tipo do campo na base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, o objeto do `Type` `DateTime` tem a propriedade `TimeOfDay` que retorna um `TimeSpan` com o horario atual.

Então é interresante converter o valor da celula `dtSolicitacao` para um `DateTime`, como o `dtSolicitacao` não é obrigatório, então usaremos o `DateTime.TryParse` para evitar erros de conversão:

```
var cultureInfo= new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
var strSolicitacao = drv.Row["dtSolicitacao"].Value as String;      
var dtSolicitacao = default(DateTime);
DateTime.TryParse(strSolicitacao, cultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtSolicitacao);
```

agora para montar o `IdentNomeHorario`, vamos testar se `dtSolicitacao` possui um valor e então montaremos a string usando um `String.Format`.

```
var strHorario = dtSolicitacao != default(DateTime) ? dtSolicitacao.TimeOfDay.ToString() : String.Empty;
var IdentNomeHorario = String.Format("</br>Nome: {0} {1}", Apelido, strHorario);
```